# Python script to automate in linux based environment

Tags: python, scripting

I tried running the `myview` command and it ran successfully, but I am stuck after this step.

I have to choose from a list of views and have to pass in a number, for example say <1>,<2>..<10>. But when I execute the script it shows me option on the terminal window instead. 
Which command should I be using? Because after this I have to run a bunch of other commands as well and basically have to execute them in a particular order. So say cmd  should wait for cmd  to finish. Thanks in advance for the help.

This is what I have so far.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
from subprocess import call
for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
call(["myview"])
```

Comment: What is `myview` command ? Is it related to windows?

Comment: Myview is basically a clearcase command so it gives you like 5-6 options. For example ) [1] view1 [2] view2 [3] Exit . And you have to chose a number

Comment: So all i have to do is use pass in [2] in my argument and give that option when the script runs. Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [doc for subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). I think the API call you need is `check_call`.

Answer (score 0):

From [`pydoc subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
try:
    retcode = call("mycmd" + " myarg", shell=True)
    if retcode < 0:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Child was terminated by signal", -retcode
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Child returned", retcode
except OSError, e:
    print >>sys.stderr, "Execution failed:", e
```

Comment: From the same docs: use a list instead, and avoid using `shell=True` if at all possible.

Comment: Just one question instead of mycmd i should write "myview" and instead of "myarg is should replace it with "2" or any other number if i do that i get this error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./popen.py", line 3, in ?
    retcode = call("myview" + " 10", shell=True)
NameError: name 'call' is not defined

Comment: @MartijnPieters what do you mean by a list. Sorry but I am totally new to this.

Comment: @user1457303: Use `call(['mycmd', 'myarg'])` (so first argument to `subprocess.` functions or `subprocess.Popen()` is a list, not a string). But do follow BenDundee's advice and read the documentation carefully.

Comment: @user1457303: Did you include `from subprocess import call`?